# Express: how to end response

Tags: node.js, express, mysqli

I new in Nodejs and faced some problems and need help

I broke down my app into modules and controllers 
in app.js

```
app.use('/api/sync', syncDataRouter)
```

and in syncDataRouter.js

```
const routes = function (con, Reading, ReadingSummary) {
    const syncDataRouter = express.Router();

    const syncDataController = require('../controller/syncDataController')(con, Reading, ReadingSummary);

    //Get All Readings from Database and push it to Mongo-db
    syncDataRouter.route('/')
        .get(syncDataController.sync);


    return syncDataRouter;

};

module.exports = routes;
```

and in controller

```
     const syncDataController = function (con, Reading, ReadingSummary) {


        function getAllCompletedSessions() {
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                const sql = 'SELECT * FROM session WHERE endTime IS NOT NULL';

                con.query(sql, (err, rows) => {
                    if (err) reject(new Error(err));
                    resolve(rows);
                });
            });
        };


        function getSessionPlayers(sessionId) {
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                const sql = 'SELECT * FROM sessionplayers WHERE sessionId = ?';

                con.query(sql, [sessionId], (err, rows) => {
                    if (err) reject(new Error(err));
                    resolve(rows);
                });
            });
        };


        const sync = (req, res) => {
            getAllCompletedSessions()
               .then(sessions => {
            })
            .catch(err => {
                res.status(500).send({ message: err.message });
            });

            //The Problem
             res.json('Done');

        };


        return {
            sync: sync
        }

   }

  module.exports = syncDataController;
```

the problem is if any error happened enter a catch block and also continue until  **res.json('Done');** and sent a message **can't set headers after they are sent** how to handle a situation like that

Comment: Why is `res.json('Done')` where you placed it? It should be inside `.then(sessions => {`.

Answer (score 0):

Try making the sql queries async

```
const syncDataController = function (con, Reading, ReadingSummary) {


        async function getAllCompletedSessions() {
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                const sql = 'SELECT * FROM session WHERE endTime IS NOT NULL';

                await con.query(sql, (err, rows) => {
                    if (err) reject(new Error(err));
                    resolve(rows);
                });
            });
        };


        async function getSessionPlayers(sessionId) {
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                const sql = 'SELECT * FROM sessionplayers WHERE sessionId = ?';

                await con.query(sql, [sessionId], (err, rows) => {
                    if (err) reject(new Error(err));
                    resolve(rows);
                });
            });
        };


        const sync = (req, res) => {
            getAllCompletedSessions()
               .then(sessions => {
            })
            .catch(err => {
                res.status(500).send({ message: err.message });
            });

            //The Problem
             res.json('Done');

        };


        return {
            sync: sync
        }

   }

  module.exports = syncDataController;
```